# Current Google homepage - why is css sprite used instead of a single image?

Tags: css, css-sprites

Look at the Google homepage being displayed  right at this moment. A screenshot is provided below.

[image: google homepage]

Instead of using this as a single image Google used css sprite. The sprite image

is provided below (dimension changed):

[image]

Question is why  css sprite was used instead of a single image ? If a single image was used then wouldn't the number of HTTP requests be same as in this css sprite case ?

Comment: Some parts of "the image" can change. That's why the big image is made of many small images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single image would not allow for (different) hover effects in different areas.

Or you would have to load an image of the same size for each animation. By using a sprite, you just have to load the image once and all animations run with that data.

Comment: So it is possible to use hover effects for different are of a css sprite ?

Comment: Basically you compose you image using different parts of the sprite. In the google example you see a general background and then a lot of small images in an overlay. A hover effect now comes down to changing the area of the sprite you use.

Answer (score 0):

`CSS` sprites are a way to reduce the number of `HTTP` requests made for `image` resources referenced by your site. **Images are combined into one larger image** at defined X and Y coordinates.

Having assigned this generated image to relevant page elements the `background-position` CSS property can then be used to shift the visible area to the required component image.

Comment: so as to the Google homepage - the sprite was used keeping other pages in mind as there are no other images in that page?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed other pages means..?? if i am understand you right than yes it is the reason..imagine one page having 500 icons displayed then browser send 500 request if you use 500 icon in single image then that will reduce that request.

Comment: Only one single image could be used there in Google homepage unless i consider what Sirko said.. am I right ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed thats depend on you...and also on how much amount of images are used repeatedly

Comment: I referenced a particular homepage

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed if you see it sprite image just used to set image as rounded corner other image with 600*200 dimension are already there too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25934/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-dipesh-parmar)